# Getting newest newspost database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the newest post from my Database. If I run the following code I get the following message:

"Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE newsposts ORDER BY newsposts.post_id DESC ' at line 2"

```
<?php
            $getPosts = mysql_query("SELECT newsposts.post_id, newsposts.post 
                     FROM TABLE newsposts 
                 ORDER BY newsposts.post_id DESC 
                    LIMIT 1") or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            while($getPosts_Array = mysql_fetch_array($getPosts)){

                $post_id = $getPosts_Array['post_id'];
                $post = $getPosts_Array['post'];

                echo "  
                            $post;


                ";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Note that this method (mysql_) is deprecated. See PDO/mysqli_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get rid of "TABLE" in your SQL statement as the `FROM` clause assumes a Table.

Answer (score 2):

First off, MySQL_* functions are deprecated and you should be using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Using PDO, grabbing the latest post is simple:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT post_id, post FROM newsposts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'Post #'.$row['post_id'].': '.$row['post']; //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT newsposts.post_id, newsposts.post 
FROM newsposts 
ORDER BY newsposts.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```